# How can I validate a full name using addMethod in jQuery Validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm currently using jQuery Validate to validate my form data, and I'm using regex for several fields to check validity using patterns. However, even after applying my new validation method via addMethod, the form still allows people to submit the form using only a first name in the full name field.

For my full name field, I've already verified my regex works by testing it on the field without using novalidate on my form.

Regex: `^([a-zA-Z]{2,}\s[a-zA-z]{1,}'?-?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?)`

addMethod attempt

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("fullname", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^([a-zA-Z]{2,}\s[a-zA-z]{1,}'?-?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?)/.test(value);
}, 'Please enter your full name.');
```

```
<input id="full-name" name="Full_Name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John Doe" required>
```

If a single name (e.g. John) is entered instead of a full name, my regex should mark it invalid and request the person's full name.

Comment: Where is your `.validate()` method?  Where is your `form`?  Without showing this, nobody knows if you're invoking the new rule correctly.

Comment: I wasn't actually aware of the `.validate()` method, hence my problem. All fixed now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- First, return `true` if you validation passes, `false` otherwise.
- Second, actually *invoke* the newly-added method in `.validate()`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("fullname", function(value, element) {
  if (/^([a-zA-Z]{2,}\s[a-zA-z]{1,}'?-?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?)/.test(value)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  };
}, 'Please enter your full name.');

$("#sample").validate({
  rules: {
    Full_Name: { // Corresponds to the `name` attribute
      required: true,
      fullname: true // Attaches the new method to the element
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The form is valid and would have been submitted successfully');
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="sample">
  <input id="full-name" name="Full_Name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John Doe" required>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the logic within his `.addMethod()` function.  `return this.optional(element) || /^([a-zA-Z]{2,}\s[a-zA-z]{1,}'?-?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s?([a-zA-Z]{1,})?)/.test(value)` will indeed give a `true` or `false` response and is using a function that is correctly structured similar to the methods [here](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/additional-methods.js).

Comment: By leaving out the `this.optional(element)` part, you are forcing the field to be `required` even when the `required` rule is `false`.  If he uses your version of his method on an optional field, one could never leave this field empty.

Comment: Perfect solution! I can't believe I forgot to invoke my new method. Thanks Obsidian!

Comment: @Obsidian running into the exact same issue on another site except that now I've implemented the same addMethod _and_ invoked the method and all the site is validating for is whether the field is filled or not. I've compared the code with the code you sent and it's identical. Any ideas?